# Android studio manifest permissions, no need to add it manually?

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions

Today i was updating one of my Apps, i was in process of migrating project to android permission and integrating admob and vungle ads sdk, I forgot to add permissions inside manifest file and I exported the apk. But apk was perfectly showing ads inside app and it showed network permissions before installing the apk.So the permissions are not mandatory to add inside android studio?

Below are the permissions which i forgot to add

```
<!-- permissions to download and cache video ads for playback -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

There are no other permissions in my app.So do i need to add it there?

Comment: Those libraries are probably automatically [adding permissions to your manifest](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html), through the manifest merger process.

Comment: @CommonsWare Then why in their sdk, they separately tell us to add those permissions?

Comment: You would have to ask them. If I had to guess, their documentation is simply out of date.